# Confused about the behavior of FOR loop with range

Tags: linux, bash

I am bit confuse with the behavior of the FOR loop.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 y=5
 echo $y
 for i in {1.. $y }
 do
   echo "This is test:$i "
 done
```

Output:

```
5  
This is test:{1..5}
```

Expected Output:

```
5  
This is test:1  
This is test:2  
This is test:3  
This is test:4  
This is test:5
```

- Shell: `/bin/bash`
- BASH Version: 4.1.2
- OS: RHEL 6.4 (Santiago)

Here I am not getting why the value of variable is not assigned in the for loop as `{1..5}`, if assigned why it is not iterating 5 times.

Comment: You cannot use a variable within the brace expansion of `{start..stop..step}`. If you need a variable size, use `seq`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks. It worked. :)

Comment: Glad it helped, I, and just about everyone else learns this lesson the hard way `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ya, I wasted couple of hours, interesting thing is that no where mentioned what you said. Thanks a lot. I should have asked 3 hrs before only.